# Mount Exchange 2003 Database in Exchange 2010 in SBS 2011?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2011, windows-sbs-2003

So the scenario I am facing is where I had an old SBS 2003 server. I used Outlook to export emails to a PST, saved on a USB and then imported them back into the new SBS 2011 server (two different physical boxes).

We have now destroyed the old box and I have just realized i forgot to export an old, very small email account. I have an image of the old server (using Backup Exec System recovery) and am basically wondering if, and how, i would be able to mount the Exchange 2003 database file from backup into my Exchange 2010 on SBS 2011 and then copy over the one mailbox.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible. you will need to install Exchange 2003 somewhere to restore the mailbox.